# What could I use to put a clickable object somewhere in a picture using Java and Swing?

Tags: java, swing, clickable

We have to do a point-and-click game this year in class, and our teachers said we had to use Java...

We began with Swing to display the pictures of the game, and we are trying to find a way to detect where in the picture is the player clicking.

I already found some answers like checking the pixels, or using a MouseListener (see [Java - Certain Regions of Components only clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131882/java-certain-regions-of-components-only-clickable) and [Java. Swing. JComponent's clickable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911842/java-swing-jcomponents-clickable-area)) as examples.

But I was wondering, can't it be easier just to put a JButton in the background, is that possible ?

Comment: For a rectangular grid, you can use the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/230513), a possible duplicate.

Comment: One could add to a JPanel (with a global background image) several shapes which could react individually. A JButton I doubt a bit.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of something like that trashgod, thank you I will try to apply it.